# What does Out Of Scope mean?

Tags: xcode, scope

I have received an error that indicates that "savedNumberDict" is Out Of Scope. I am not quite sure where to look for a solution.  Any suggestions?  The code is below that I am using. Thanks.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*) application {
    self.savedNumber = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:kNumberLocationKey];

    if (savedNumber == nil) {
        savedNumber = @"555 555 1212";
        NSDictionary *savedNumberDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:savedNumber forKey:kNumberLocationKey];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:savedNumberDict ];
    }

    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible]; 
}
```

Comment: Since that isn't a compilable fragment, we need to know which line reports the probem.  It certainly isn't immediately obvious how the code shown could have savedNumberDict out of scope since it is defined inside a { ... } scope and the only reference to it shown is inside the same scope.  Silly Q time: are you sure this is the code that has the error?

Answer (score 1):

Is this piece of code definitely the root of the error?  Are you not trying to access savedNumberDict elsewhere?  Since it is declared inside your if {} block, it only exists within the if {}, once the code exits that block the variable ceases to exist.